# Store value with area keys instead unique key in kotlin?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, hashmap, range

Accidentally discovered the magic ability in Kotlin to record value with keys area in kotlin

```
    private val durationFromAngel:HashMap<ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float>, Long> = 
 hashMapOf(1F..4F to 15L, 5F..9F to 150L, 10F..14F to 300L, 15F..29F to 700L)
```

But haven't idea how work with this in case if i have uniqe input key

Next isn't correct.

```
   val value = durationFromAngel[5F]
```

But i want get via this value 5F from range 1F..5F

Comment: @JonasWilms but if i have one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hashmap won't really help you as you cannot look up by key. Instead use a List and find the range you are looking for:

```
 val durationFromAngel =  listOf(
   1F..4F      to 15L, 
   5F..9F      to 150L, 
   10F..14F    to 300L, 
   15F..29F    to 700L
)

val (_, result) = durationFromAngel.find { (range) -> 6F in range }!!
println(result)
```

For sure you can also add an extension function as:

```
 operator fun <N: Comparable<N>, T> List<Pair<ClosedFloatingPointRange<N>, T>>.get(value: N) =
    this.find { (range) -> value in range }!!

val (range, value) = durationFromAngel[6f]
println(value)
```

but thats just syntactic sugar.

[Try it!](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/ekk5fjroh42hpht6rtuueoao6j/3n7pnb9v5v1m0m5563ifa6tanp)

Comment: @serg whoops, not quite awake yet, should work now (`it` was a `Pair`)

Comment: @SergBurlaka yes, had the same idea, I prefer using destructuring here :)

Comment: nullablbe destructor, i edited also. Can you review?

Comment: @SergBurlaka and I was faster again ... I prefer using the `!!` here, using a cusstom error works too

Comment: yehh, you was first for some seconds:). Today i learned some of new in kotlin syntax. Many thanks!